# Quelle est la différence entre les mots « manière » et « façon » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, locutions

Dans quelles situations peut-on utiliser ces mots ?

Y a-t-il une différence d'utilisation ou de sens ?

Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre :

> Il a quitté leur pays de manière illégale.

et

> Il a quitté leur pays de façon illégale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de grosse différence d'utilisation ou de sens entre ces deux termes, ils sont d'ailleurs souvent considérés comme synonymes.

Cependant, on peut parfois employer l'un plutôt que l'autre pour des raisons de style ou lorsqu'ils font partie d'une expression. Par exemple, dans l'expression suivante, j'aurais tendance à dire :

> Sa façon d'être.

plutôt que :

> Sa manière d'être.

Comment: À noter qu'ils ne sont pas synonymes dans toutes leurs acceptions. _Façon_ a aussi un sens proche de _fabriqué_ (voir _façonner_ et _contrefaçon_) et je crois que le sens synonyme de _manière_ (qui domine de nos jours tandis que l'autre est plus ou moins vieilli suivant les contextes) s'est acquis par extension de ce sens là.

Comment: Les ngrams pour [*de façon* et *de manière*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+manière%2C+de+façon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19) sont particulièrement intrigants.

Comment: Merci de votre suivi

Comment: @Unfrancophone : et à l'inverse "faire des façons" ne peut pas remplacer "faire des manières" ce qui donne "être maniéré"

Answer (score 5):

On peut essayer de les différencier en fonction du verbe adjoint :

*Façon* est lié à l'action de faire, et s'emploie de préférence avec un verbe d'action.

*Manière* en est la forme : manière d'agir de se conduire, de vivre, d'être. Il s'emploie de préférence avec un verbe d'état qui induit un effet sur autrui.

> La meilleure *façon* d'marcher c'est encore la nôtre, c'est de mettre un
>   pied d'vant l'autre et de recommencer (Chanson souvent utilisée par les groupes de jeunes).

L'art et la *manière*, employer la *manière* forte (locutions).

> Il est *maniéré* : péjoratif, il complique sa façon d'agir par des
>   attitudes superfétatoires.

Mais on ne peut pas dire il est *façonné* qui n'est utilisé que pour les objets.

> *Je n'aime pas ces manières* de parler : je n'aime pas cette forme d'expression (en ciblant plutôt le choix des mots, l'expression théâtralisée  du locuteur).
>
> *Je n'aime pas ces façons de parler* : je n'aime pas les mots, le sens donné à la phrase (en ciblant plutôt le texte prononcé, l'attitude morale du locuteur).

Mais on peut interchanger ces deux mots sans modifier le sens de la phrase, mis à part quelques locutions.